# how to create entity without duplicates

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following code in my controller:

```
 foreach ($image->tags as $tag) {
            $existingTag = $em->getRepository('AppMainBundle:InstagramTag')->findOneByTag($tag);

             if ($existingTag) {
                ladybug_dump('existing tag');
             } else {
                ladybug_dump('non existing tag');
                $instagramTag = new InstagramTag();
                $instagramTag->setTag($tag);
                $em->persist($instagramTag);
              }                     
  }
```

Here's my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_instagram_tag")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class InstagramTag
{
     /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="tag", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $tag;

     /**
     *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\MainBundle\Entity\InstagramPictureTag", mappedBy="tag")
     */
    private $picturetag;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get tag
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTag()
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    /**
     * Set tag
     *
     * @param string $tag
     * @return InstagramTag
     */
    public function setTag( $tag)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

I initially started with an empty table called app_instagram_tag. And $image->tags is an array of strings, for example `["abc", "test", "etc"]`. How is it possible that when I started using an empty table then it prints `existing tag` all the time?

Comment: Show the code of your repo method `findOneByTag`

Comment: @Bram It's probably one of Doctrine's magic methods

Comment: You should probably have a unique constraint on your `tag` property. Other than that, can't see anything wrong with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@adit, in theory $existingTag should be 'NULL'. Try to var_dump($existingTag) and see which values you have into this variable. Also, if I were you I'd change the code to :

```
<?php
...
$repository = $em->getRepository('AppMainBundle:InstagramTag');

foreach ($image->tags as $tag) {
    $existingTag = $repository->findOneByTag($tag);

    if ($existingTag) {

        var_dump($existingTag); // this line is just to find out why your logic is falling in here when should go to the else. Maybe change the logic for if ($existingTag === NULL) {
        ladybug_dump('existing tag');

        } else {
                ladybug_dump('non existing tag');
                $instagramTag = new InstagramTag();
                $instagramTag->setTag($tag);
                $em->persist($instagramTag);
        }                     
  }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
 if(isset($existingTag)) {
 }
```

instead of

```
if ($existingTag)
```